# Change post category within pre_get_posts

Tags: categories, pre-get-posts

I have written a filter to be called in `pre_get_posts` to remove posts from a category page based on a `meta_key` (`EventDate` which is in the form `YYYYMMDD`), which is working.

However I'm struggling with the next step, which is to change the category of the now excluded post. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working?

I have tried:

```
function pre_get_posts_filter($query){
    if($query->is_main_query()){
        if(is_archive()):
            if(is_category($category='Events')):
                $a=array();
                if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),$key='EventDate',$single=true)<date('Ymd')):
                    $query->set('post__not_in', array_push($a,get_the_ID()));
                    wp_set_post_categories(get_the_ID(),array('PastEvents'));
                 else:
                   //Set the order ASC or DESC
                   $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
                   //Set the orderby
                   $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num');
                   $query->set('meta_key', 'EventDate');
                endif;
            endif;
        endif; 
        return $query;
    }
    };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You can't do this at this stage. The posts haven't been queried yet (*pre*_get_posts after all), so there's no post to set the category on. If you want to change the category of 'expired' posts then that's something best done as part of a recurring background event, not as part of the query for a category archive.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for the quick reply. That would definitely explain why it wouldn't work! Time to look at wordpress cron jobs.